# persistLong not working even if I put literal inside - ClassCastException

Tags: java, android

I've a quite strange problem. First please take a look at my code. I have made my custom class which extends EditTextPreference, and I overrode onClick(DialogInterface, which) method.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);

        switch(which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

            long currentDelay = (Long.parseLong(getEditText().getText().toString())*1000);

            if(currentDelay < 0.5) {

                getEditText().setText("1000");
                currentDelay = 1000;
            }

            persistLong(currentDelay); // Crashes (Even if I put literal inside)
            persistString(getEditText().getText().toString()); // It works  
        break;

        }
```

If onclick method is executed, persistLong always crashes my program and it throws ClassCastException. Even if I put literal in parameters (like ,persistLong(4000) ). On the other way, persistString works just fine.

What could be the problem here? Any suggestions?

EDIT: My LogCat: Line 59 is where persistLong method is.

```
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong(ContextImpl.java:2939)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedLong(Preference.java:1388)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.preference.Preference.persistLong(Preference.java:1359)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.callandsmsled.MyEditTextPreference.onClick(MyEditTextPreference.java:59)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
03-05 15:51:14.212: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is probably happening because `EditTextPeference` is specifically used to store text strings, per the documentation.

Comment: Probably yes. Okay never mind. I will parse string on the other end then. Thank you.